# Why can I not have two separate dispatch groups?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

When I try to create two separate dispatch groups in swift, my code crashes at the creation of the first one, however when I comment out either one the code runs fine.  Below are my two dispatch groups.  I need the code to run at separate times so I need two separate groups.  Perhaps I am initializing these incorrectly?

```
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
        {
            if self.z == 0{


            self.viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(self.markers[self.x!], zoom: 16.9)
                print(self.markers.count)
                if self.markers.count > 0 {
                    self.marker = GMSMarker(position: self.markers[0])
                    print(self.marker)
                    print(self.markers[0])
                    self.downloadVideo(self.marker)
                }

            }else{

            }

        });

    dispatch_group_notify(groupVideo, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
                          {
                            if(self.tempLat!.roundToPlaces(3) == self.markerLat.roundToPlaces(3) && self.tempLong!.roundToPlaces(3) == self.markerLong.roundToPlaces(3)){
                                print("success")
                                self.postsLat = self.tempLat
                                self.postsLong = self.tempLong
                            }else {
                                print("not a success")
                            }

    });
```

They are initialized like so:

```
let group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();
let groupVideo: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create();
```

And entered and exited like so:

```
dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
dispatch_group_exit(self.group);
```

In two separate functions

```
dispatch_group_enter(self.groupVideo);
dispatch_group_exit(self.groupVideo);
```

Comment: What's the error? Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: the variable group is found as nil when I assign groupVideo as well, so it cannot run either dispatch group

Comment: There's not enough here to reproduce your problem. But we don't want to see more of your actual code. I'd suggest you create a [simplified example that completely reproduces the problem in question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you.

Comment: But, in short, there's nothing that prevents you from using two different groups. It works fine. The problem rests in how you're using these two groups, not in the fact that you are using two groups.